# Async Auto Save in angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am trying to create an autosave in typescript. The goal is to get whatever user types in and save it automatically every 10 seconds so user will not lose what ever they have typed in even if page crash or they close it accidentally.
I want to start the autosaving process as soon the page has finished been loaded.

I have written something like this :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.autoSaveContent();
}

private  autoSaveContent() {
    while (true) {
        if (this.isSaving == false && this.hasContentChanged() == true) {
            this.content.status = 1;
            setTimeout(this.saveContent(), 10000)
        }
    }

}
```

How do I run the code asynchronously? Because I want this process to be run constantly when the page is opened. This way the content can always be saved.

Answer (score 3):

setInterval() should check every 10 seconds for changes... Something like this...

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.autoSaveContent();
}

private  autoSaveContent() {
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        if (that.isSaving == false && that.hasContentChanged() == true) {
            that.saveContent();
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

For ES6, you can use fat arrow and not worry about capturing "this" in your closure:

```
private  autoSaveContent() {
    setInterval(() => {
        if (this.isSaving == false && this.hasContentChanged() == true) {
            this.saveContent();
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above should work! only the problem I can see is, you should pass function reference in `setTimeout` method instead of calling it there.

```
setTimeout(this.saveContent.bind(this), 10000)
```

**OR**

```
setTimeout(() => { this.saveContent() }, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, however I found out there is a timer in Observable, so I solved it by using the timer.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isPageAlive = true;
    let timer = Observable.timer(10000, 10000);
    let subscription = timer.subscribe(x => this.autoSaveContent());
}

private autoSaveContent() {
    if (this.isSaving == false && this.hasContentChanged() == true) {
        this.content.status = 1;
        this.saveContent();
    }

}
```